# Raspberry Pi Ethernet port not working after thunderstorm

Tags: hardware, archlinux, ethernet, ethernet-port

I have a Raspberry Pi (512 Mb ram) running Arch Linux ARM, connected to my router working as a vpn server.

After a thunderstorm, the Ethernet port stopped working. It won't even blink anymore. The rest of the raspberry, along with the usb ports work fine.

When I try to get the interface up from linux, I get `hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup`

The router it was connected to was completely burned as well, so I suppose it's just the Ethernet port that has the problem.

Is there a way to fix the port? Is there something I can do?

Comment: can you see any physical damage? burns broken tracks etc? For the price just buy a new Pi, a decent USB->Ethernet adapter is not much cheaper.

Comment: same behavior after reboot?

Comment: Yes, it's the same after every reboot.
Can't see any physical damage.

Everything else works, so I don't want to throw it away just because the ethernet port is dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its just the ethernet, and everything else is fully functional , could add a usb wifi dongle and use it as a wifi sensor board/server.
Should be able to get a usb wifi dongle from around $8 + p&h.

Answer (score 2):

Your board was likely fried in the storm, or at least the Ethernet port. Given the price of hardware replacement vs fixing the Ethernet port, I recommend swapping out the board.  Consider this an ideal excuse to upgrade to the new Pi 2.